# Login Module - Customising Error Messages

Tags: joomla, module

Does anybody know how I would go about changing the styling of the error message associated with the Joomla login module. For example, an error message is "Username and password do not match or you do not have an account yet", it is on an orange background so I would like to change that and the border colour if at all possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use css styles for:

```
#system-message-container {} //messages container
#system-message-container dl#system-message {} //message
#system-message-container dl#system-message dt.error{} //title error
#system-message-container dl#system-message dd.error{} //description error
#system-message-container dl#system-message dt.warning{} //title warning
#system-message-container dl#system-message dd.warning{} //description warning
#system-message-container dl#system-message dt.notice{} //title notice
#system-message-container dl#system-message dd.notice{} //description notice
```

Comment: You'd want to do what Tsyba said by modifying the variables.les and recompiling.

Comment: Instead of changing core files and compile your stuff, one could also use one of the many extensions on JED which allow to add custom CSS.